# Connect to Amazon EMR serverless using JDBC

Tags: jdbc, hive, amazon-emr

Below steps is to connect to Amazon EMR running on EC2 cluster to SQL workbench. The approach is to connect to EMR using the master node of EC2 cluster. However in case of Amazon EMR serverless, there is no master node.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/HiveJDBCDriver.html

Is there any way to connect to Amazon EMR serverless? I am not looking for any specific SQL client to connect to Amazon EMR serverless. Any SQL Client works for me. Please help.

Comment: Not at this time, EMR Serverless doesn't have an interactive endpoint, just batch jobs.